# Hadoop GroupingComparatorClass.compare method is not getting called

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have created a hadoop job where I `job.setGroupingComparatorClass` with a comparator class (`PathDateComparator`) that I've created. When running the job I can see that the constructor for `PathDateComparator` is getting called but the compare function isn't.

Here is the `PathDateComparator` class:

```
public class PathDateComparator extends WritableComparator {

    protected PathDateComparator() {
        super(Text.class, true);
        System.out.println("PathDateComparator");
    }

    private String getPath(String s) {
        System.out.println("s:" + s);
        String[] temp = s.split(IOUtil.tab);
        return temp[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String k1 = ((Text) o1).toString();
        System.out.println("k1:" + k1);
        String path1 = getPath(k1);
        System.out.println("path1:" + path1);

        String k2 = ((Text) o2).toString();
        System.out.println("k2:" + k2);
        String path2 = getPath(k2);
        System.out.println("path2:" + path2);

        return path1.compareTo(path2);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable o1, WritableComparable o2) {
        String k1 = ((Text) o1).toString();
        System.out.println("k1:" + k1);
        String path1 = getPath(k1);
        System.out.println("path1:" + path1);

        String k2 = ((Text) o2).toString();
        System.out.println("k2:" + k2);
        String path2 = getPath(k2);
        System.out.println("path2:" + path2);

        return path1.compareTo(path2);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] bArray1, int offset1, int length1,
            byte[] bArray2, int offset2, int length2) {

        String k1 = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(bArray1, offset1, offset1 + length1));
        System.out.println("k1:" + k1);
        String path1 = getPath(k1);
        System.out.println("path1:" + path1);

        String k2 = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(bArray2, offset2, offset2 + length2));
        System.out.println("k2:" + k2);
        String path2 = getPath(k2);
        System.out.println("path2:" + path2);

        return path1.compareTo(path2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you looking for the sysout statements (which log file) they will most probably be in the reducer task logs (in the map task logs too if you have a combiner configured).

Comment: @ChrisWhite I'm testing locally right now so all the output/logging is going to the cli. For instance I have a `SortComparatorClass` set and I can see the output from within the calls to it's `compare` method.

Comment: Can you share more of your code (job driver)

Answer (score 0):

The class you reference (PathDateComparator, here) needs to be an implementor of RawComparator.  The compare method looks right, though.  The idea is that the class is used only to compare key values encoded as byte arrays.

Comment: After adding `implements RawComparator` I'm still not seeing any of the println output except for the "PathDateComparator" that's output from the constructor.